# C# - I want to hit Enter, not click on the "button" to activate program

Tags: c#

I'm just learning C#. I created a Windows Form Application. It works, but you have to click on the "Calculate" button that I created to activate the program. I would like to be able to just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on my keyboard. I thought maybe there was a properties setting for the button but I don't see one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for [`Form.AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.90).ASPX) property

> Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user presses the ENTER key.

Comment: It's worth noting the behavior of a non null Form.AcceptButton property and a textbox that has `AcceptsReturn = true`

Answer (score 2):

You could listen for the KeyUp event

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void btnSubmit_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        MessageBox.Show("You hit the Enter key.");
}
```